# nCover With many class libraries

Tags: nunit, ncover

So I have my project and it is set up like this:

MyProject
MyProject.Module1
MyProject.Module1.Tests
MyProject.Module2
MyProject.Module2.Tests

What I want is the code coverage number for the entire project.

I am using nCover... what is the best way to do this?  For example would I have to rearrange the project and have everything put into MyProject.Tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're testing. Most test frameworks will let you run tests for multiple assemblies as separate arguments. If you can't run them all together, you can always use NCover's merge feature. Check out http://docs.ncover.com/ref/2-0/ncoverexplorer-console/merging-coverage-data/.